# High Availability Of MooseFS Master

Tags: apache-zookeeper, moosefs

I have a setup where we are running 1 Master  and 3 chunk servers . In case one of my chunk servers goes down My set up is working fine .I want the same functionality with my Master server too .How can I do that ?

My exact need is : I am going to have 2 master servers and if one goes down 2nd one should act as master

Answer (score 3):

You should try LizardFS http://lizardfs.com and on http://github.com/lizardfs/lizardfs , its fork of MooseFS and have build in master ha compability.

The simplest way is to have in eg. keepalived with virtual ip bind to this virtual ip master server and deploy second master server on diffrent machine but in config you need to set PERSONALITY from master to shadow.
When first master going down and keepalived swith ip to second machine you need change back PERSONALITY to master nad reload master server.

If you write correct config for keepalived you can get 1-2 sec downtime.

Comment: Thank you ...I had found this solution but this does not solve my purpose as here the systems I am using are Mac-binded servers.So ,for a single mac I cannot assign multiple IPs (primary and secondary ).I need some mechanism like If the master goes Off it will change my master server IP in slave servers.I heard this can be implemented using zookeeper.

Comment: This is not an answer as LizardFS is not compatible with MooseFS any longer.

Comment: @Jakub So? It's still an answer if someone is using old software.

Answer (score 2):

MooseFS 2.0 Pro have master HA

http://moosefs.com/support.html
"2 – Premium Software Features includes Master HA."

http://moosefs.com/products.html
left menu -> card Overview

Comment: MooseFS is no longer a free software; It doesn't have freely downloadable sources any more...

Comment: MooseFS is GPLv2. You can find MooseFS source code here: [github.com/moosefs/moosefs](https://github.com/moosefs/moosefs). Just part of it (Master Server High Availability and Erasure Coding) is excluded from GPL.

Answer (score 1):

MooseFS in version >= 2.0 Pro have Master HA